# Compare current and previous value

Tags: c#

I have a loop where I get my value as

```
var val= (from entry in Data select (entry.Value)).ToList().First();
```

Data is a `Dictionary` which I am using temporarily, `val` is of type double. 
so I have

```
foreach(var v in val)
  if(v > 100){
  // here I wanna check if the difference between current and last value is greaterthan 10, to skip the setValue and exit the foreach loop. 

     a.setValue(v);

     }
```

Now I don't want to set the value if the difference between current and previous is more than 10.

Should I create a list or something ?

Comment: Wait a minute. You say: "`val` is `double`" and you do "foreach(var v in val)"? How to iterate on double???

Comment: what is the 'a' variable?

Comment: sorry, it's an Option<double>, didn't wanna bother with that,its just a nullable custom type, so I need to foreach, but anyhow am looping before this for each value

Comment: @justanidiot, please improve your question. Give a working example of your code - not just random lines with errors. I guess I know what you want, but I'm confused which literal is what.

Comment: you cannot loop with type double. o_0

Comment: If you're iterating a dictionary then the items are not logically ordered, so comparing an item to it's next/previous isn't meaningful.  You'd need to order the items if you want such comparisons to mean anything.

Comment: its not a dictionary, I am temporary using that to hold a list of values coming at run time

Comment: @justanidiot The point remains; when you added the items to a dictionary their order was all jumbled up; since you haven't ordered the items since taking them out they are in some arbitrary order.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? This will store the previous value in another variable and then compare with the current value of v.

```
decimal previousVal = 0;

foreach(var v in val)
{
    if(previousVal > 0)
    {
        if(Math.Abs(v - previousVal) > 10) 
        {
           // diff greater than 10
        }
    }
    a.setValue(v);
    previousVal = v;
}
```

*edit:*

The `0` is just an indication of whether or not this is the first iteration through the loop. If `0` is a potential value, you could use a nullable decimal instead:

```
decimal ? previousVal = null;

foreach(var v in val)
{
    if(previousVal != null)
    {
        if(Math.Abs(v - previousVal) > 10) 
        {
           // diff greater than 10
        }
    }
    a.setValue(v);
    previousVal = v;
}
```

Comment: but them, am interested otherwise, like I wanna do something when the condition is less than 10, so now in this case, first iteration will only work if i is greater than 0, I want to add first iteration,2nd,3rd until the Math.Abs(v - previousVal) > 10

Comment: but in this case, if null, am not gonna enter the if clause, and I need to do that, coz like this i'll miss the first value,first iteration

Comment: @justanidiot the value of the first iteration will be stored in v, and there is no previous value to compare it to, so we already know the difference isn't greater than 10. it will be compared with the 2nd value on the 2nd iteration.

Comment: But when its greater, I want to stop reading v and exit the foreach, as then am not interested in anymore values

Answer (score 0):

Is something like [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) what you're looking for?

```
var numbers = new []{ 1, 2, 3, 40, 41 };

var differences = numbers.Skip(1).Zip(numbers, (prev, curr) => Math.Abs(prev - curr));

var result = numbers.TakeWhile((obj, index) => index == 0 || numbers[index - 1] <= 10);

// outputs:
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 40
```

Comment: first iteration,val=10,2nd 11,12, when its 21 I wanna know :P

Comment: @justanidiot Sorry your question is very unclear. Please could you expand it to be more specific about what you want?

Comment: I am reading Val at runtime, and I add it for each value read. I want to stop adding, if the last val value differed by more than 10, i wanna stop adding

Comment: yes but am comparing only the last two values, if you see above its clearer now i edited the solution, so the previous value method looks more attractive, only i can't use that answer above, i need the opposite as per the comments

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, please consider trying this:

```
//List<double> 
var list = (from entry in Data select (entry.Value)).ToList();

double previousValue = 0;
for (int i=0; i< list.Count; i++)
{
    var diff = list[i] - previousValue;
    if (diff <= 10)
        a.setValue(list[i]);

    previousValue = list[i];
}
```

Comment: but am only interested in two values, a list is too much right ?